# Why are digital signature algorithms in .NET restricted to using only platform implemented hash algorithms?

Tags: c#, hash, rsa, digital-signature, ecdsa

The following C# code generates an ECDsa signature:

```cs
using ECDsa algorithm = ECDsa.Create();
byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
byte[] signature = algorithm.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
```

The following C# code generates an RSA signature:

```cs
using RSA algorithm = RSA.Create();
byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
byte[] signature = algorithm.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
```

In both cases, I'm forced to pass in `HashAlgorithmName` (rather than just `HashAlgorithm`) to generate a signature:

- [ECDsa.SignData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.signdata?view=net-8.0)
- [RSA.SignData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.signdata?view=net-8.0)

There are no method overloads that allow me to pass in `HashAlgorithm`, therefore this seems like a limiting factor as I'm only able to use hash algorithms provided by .NET and unable to use other hash algorithms when signing data.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Some signature standards package the signature in an ASN.1 structure that includes an object identifier that identifies the hash function used in that signature. I avoid understanding the .Net crypto stuff because I find the documentation so poor that it's painful to read, so I'm not exactly sure what .Net is doing.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk if that's the limiting factor, what's wrong with an overload that takes a `HashAlgorithm` and an identifier? Do the identifiers have to be well formed and conform to a format, or are they free text?

Comment: Object identifiers, or OIDs, are not just text, they are structured byte sequences that are centrally managed and assigned. In principle, an overload could be provided that lets you supply an instance of an Object Identifier class.